# Dotliquid not parsing object array in liquid template

Tags: c#, .net-core, liquid, dotliquid

I am trying following liquid template to process with dotliquid c# library, but it doesn't parse the template

Test.liquid file :

```
{% assign fruits = [
  {"name": "Apple", "price": 1.99},
  {"name": "Banana", "price": 0.99},
  {"name": "Orange", "price": 1.49}
] %}

[
{% for fruit in fruits %}
  "{{ fruit.name }} - ${{ fruit.price }}",
{% endfor %}
]
```

Comment: I've had success with Fluid; https://github.com/sebastienros/fluid

Comment: I am already using dotliquid library, so I need to achieve with this.